# RVT load issue to the Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

When you upload the file to the bucket , when you click on the file number 1 you receive the error number 2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojK5b.png)

need to understand why we revive the translation error from forge

Comment: Sorry, since the information you provided is limited, we cannot know why it failed. The straight-forward way is to call [GET :urn/manifest](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET) to check if any error message show up in the response, not to use the bucket manager sample.

Comment: To do that, you can make use of [VScode extension](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/forge-visual-studio-code) or play APS Model Derivative API by Postman. Here are my [Postman scripts](https://github.com/yiskang/forge.api.postman)